# How to override configuration?

Tags: go

We have configuration file per deploy environment, as shown in below code:

configs/.dev.env

```
  deploy_env=dev
```

configs/.env

```
  deploy_env=local
```

---

main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
)

func main() {
    err := godotenv.Load("./configs/.env") // load
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to load")
    }
    err = godotenv.Load("./configs/.dev.env") // expecting to override configuration
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("unable to load")
    }
    fmt.Println(os.Getenv("deploy_env")) // Got output as: local       
                                         // Expecting output: dev
}
```

---

How to override configuration? expecting `deploy_env` to set as `dev`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Overload` instead of `Load`

[source](https://github.com/joho/godotenv/blob/add39c6f94ba6aedc178b80b33eb9f2d6ae8f2ec/godotenv.go#L64)